# How does augmenting a psionic power with multiple augmentation options work?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, psionics

I can't really seem to find clarification on this. I'm playing a Marksman in a Pathfinder campaign, it's my first time using psionics, and I'm trying to figure out how augments work in the event there are multiple augment options. For example, here's the augmentation for the Precognition, Defensive:

> You can augment this power in one or both of the following ways.
>
> For every 3 additional power points you spend, the insight bonus
>   gained increases by 1.
>
> If you spend 6 additional power points, you can manifest this power as
>   a swift action

If I spend 6 power points to manifest as a swift action, does that automatically count as also spending 2 x 3 additional points for the insight bonus? So, spending 6 additional points gets me 2 insight bonuses plus I can manifest it as the swift action? Or do I need to spend 12 points to get the same effect?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In your example, you would need to spend 12 additional power points to both manifest as a swift action and increase the bonus by 2.

This is addressed in the ["Psionic powers" overview](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/psionics-unleashed/psionic-powers), at the very bottom.

> Many powers can be augmented in more than one way. When the Augment section contains numbered paragraphs, you need to spend power points separately for each of the numbered options. When a paragraph in the Augment section begins with “In addition,” you gain the indicated benefit according to how many power points you have already decided to spend on manifesting the power.

Comment: Ah, okay, so in the instance of Trick Shot, say I chose to use the third augment, then the last sentence would then also apply because it's not a numbered option? http://www.d20pfsrd.com/psionics-unleashed/psionic-powers/t/trick-shot

Comment: Yes, it would apply.

Comment: Extra note, remember that you can never spend more points on a single ability than your manifester level. In the case of Precognition which is a first level power, this means that the Swift version cannot be used until level 7.